# Maybe create a PHP class? How to trim and make an example script more dynamic

Tags: php

Looks like the question got deleted when I was pasting code.

I have included two functions below.  One is a function for logging in and obtaining a session id, and the latter function is for getting some meta data, which uses the session id obtained form the Login(); function.

I have a feeling that this script can be cleaned up immensely, but every time I attempt to do so it breaks.

Is there a more elegant way of sending data than fput?
Is there a more elegant way of parsing an XML response that using the between(); before(); and after(); functions?
Can this script be made more dynamic to eventually be used in a library of sorts?

I have an understanding of how PHP classes can be used, but I have no where to start.

```
<?php 

    function Login () {

    // Host, Servlet, Port, and Time Out information
    $host='host.example.com';
    $servlet='XMLAPI';
    $port='80'; 
    $time_out='20';

    // Username and Password Variables

    $username = 'SomeUserId';
    $password = 'Somepassword';

    $sock = fsockopen ($host, $port, $errno, $errstr, $time_out);
    $data = "xml=<?xml version=\"1.0\"?><Envelope><Body><Login>"; 
    $data .= "<USERNAME>" . $username . "</USERNAME>"; 
    $data .= "<PASSWORD>" . $password . "</PASSWORD>"; 
    $data .= "</Login></Body></Envelope>"; 
    $size = strlen ($data); 

        if (!$sock) { 
            print("Could not connect to host:". $errno . $errstr); 
            return (false); 
        }

    fputs ($sock, "POST /servlet/" . $servlet . " HTTP/1.1\n"); 
    fputs ($sock, "Host: " . $host . "\n"); 
    fputs ($sock, "Content-type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded\n"); 
    fputs ($sock, "Content-length: " . $size . "\n"); 
    fputs ($sock, "Connection: close\n\n"); 
    fputs ($sock, $data); 
    $buffer = ""; 

        while (!feof ($sock)) { 
        $buffer .= fgets ($sock); 
        }

    fclose ($sock); 
    //print ($buffer);
    return ($buffer);

    }

    $xml_response = Login();
    session_start();
    $_SESSION['JsessionID'] = between ("<SESSION_ENCODING>","</SESSION_ENCODING>", $xml_response);


    function GetMetaData () {

    // List metadata id
    $list_id = "7238776";

    // Assign JSessionID from Login();
    $JsessionID = $_SESSION['JsessionID'];

    // Host, Servlet, Port, and Time Out information
    $host='host.example.com';
    $servlet = 'XMLAPI' . $JsessionID;
    $port='80'; 
    $time_out='20';

    $sock = fsockopen ($host, $port, $errno, $errstr, $time_out);

        if (!$sock) { 
            print("Could not connect to host:". $errno . $errstr); 
            return (false); 
        }

    $data = "xml=<?xml version=\"1.0\"?><Envelope><Body>"; 
    $data .= "<GetListMetaData><LIST_ID>" . $list_id . "</LIST_ID>"; 
    $data .= "</GetListMetaData></Body></Envelope>"; 
    $size = strlen ($data); 

    fputs ($sock, "POST /servlet/" . $servlet . " HTTP/1.1\n"); 
    fputs ($sock, "Host: " . $host . "\n"); 
    fputs ($sock, "Content-type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded\n"); 
    fputs ($sock, "Content-length: " . $size . "\n"); 
    fputs ($sock, "Connection: close\n\n"); 
    fputs ($sock, $data); 
    $buffer = ""; 

        while (!feof ($sock)) { 
        $buffer .= fgets ($sock); 
        }

    fclose ($sock); 
    print ($buffer);
    return ($buffer);

    }

    //XML Parsing Functions

    function between ($this, $that, $inthat) { 
      return before($that, after($this, $inthat)); 
    }; 

    function before ($this, $inthat) { 
        return substr($inthat, 0, strpos($inthat, $this)); 
    }; 

    function after ($this, $inthat) { 
        if (!is_bool(strpos($inthat, $this))) 
        return substr($inthat, strpos($inthat,$this)+strlen($this)); 
    }; 

    // XML Parsing of GetMetaData(); function
    $xml_response = GetMetaData();

    $id = between ("<ID>","</ID>", $xml_response);
    $last_name = between ("<NAME>LAST_NAME</NAME>\n<VALUE>","</VALUE>", $xml_response);

    print($id)
    ?>
```

Comment: Maybe do StackOverflow a favor and ...

Comment: Maybe you could actually **ask a question** instead of just posting a lot of code?

Comment: Sorry, I copied over the question when pasting the code. Updated

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Look into [SoapClient](http://php.net/manual/en/class.soapclient.php).  I suspect you are trying to make calls to a web service, and your code could be compressed to something like this:

```
$client = new SoapClient('http://path/to/wsdl');
$session_id = $client->__call('Login', array($username, $password));

$metadata = $client->__call('GetListMetaData', array($session_id, '7238776'));
$id = $metadata->id;
$last_name = $metadata->last_name;
```

Comment: Do all webservices have SOAP support?

Comment: @Taylor, no, REST is another popular method, but your example appears to be using SOAP messages.

Comment: Here is a typical response:

Envelope> 
<Body> 
<RESULT> 
<SUCCESS>TRUE</SUCCESS> 
<ID>112323</ID> 
<NAME>TestData</NAME> 
<TYPE>1</TYPE> 
<SIZE>0</SIZE> 
<LAST_MODIFIED>09/01/10 11:56 AM</LAST_MODIFIED> 
<LAST_CONFIGURED>05/18/10 04:34 PM</LAST_CONFIGURED>
</RESULT>
</Body>
</Envelope>

Comment: @Taylor, I highly recommend experimenting with the SoapClient, I think it will handle all of the low level stuff for you.  You don't have to specify a WSDL if you don't have one, put null in the constructor if you don't have a WSDL.  Try doing a `var_dump($client->__call('Login', array($username, $password));` and look at the structure it returns.

Comment: I will take a look into the documentation, however, I really am at a loss for what this is calling.  Do you not have to supply a hostname?